# Date calculation in formula

Tags: formula, date

I have created a formula field `Date__c`. In this date field, I want to calculate the following:

```
Renewal_Date__c + 1year + Extension__c
```

The value entered in `Extension__c` is in months.

So, I have the following formula:

```
DATE(  (YEAR( Renewal_Date__c )+1), (MONTH( Renewal_Date__c )+ Extension__c ) ,DAY( Renewal_Date__c))
```

The formula works fine if I leave out the `+Extension__c` part. How can I make it work so that I can add the number of months as well?

Tia, Lily.

Comment: Can you just not put Extension __c within the Month(Renewal_Date)?

Comment: If I change the formula to: `DATE(  (YEAR( Renewal_Date__c )+1), (MONTH( Renewal_Date__c + Extension__c )) ,DAY( Renewal_Date__c))`, the month value is simply ignored.

Comment: And Extension is an Integer?

Comment: Yes, `Data Type = Number`.
I tried hardcoding something, and that also gave me an error. When I write: `DATE(  (YEAR( Renewal_Date__c )+1), (MONTH( Renewal_Date__c )+ 9 ) ,DAY( Renewal_Date__c))`, I would expect to add an additional 9 months, but it seems this is not the case. I get an error in the field instead. Maybe I am using the months calculation incorrectly...

Comment: What's the value in Renewal_Date__c? If the value of that field and the Extension__c field add up to more than 12 it will give an error obviously.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add time to a Date field, you need to do that in days. So start with the Renewal Date, then add 1 year (365 days) and any other days from the Extension.

```
Renewal_Date__c + 365 + ( ( 365 / 12 ) * Extension__c )
```

Because months can vary in length, you need to use the approximation of a month (365 days divided by 12) and multiply that with the extension.